# Inject a JavaScript class in an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm working on a site where you have to install a chrome extension to be able to use it. The thing is that I'm creating the android app with a WebView element and I need to take some code of the extension and inject the code in the WebView before it finished to load the page.

The JavaScript code I need to inject is a full class.

What I have already done :

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://mysiteurl.com/");
    }
}
```

I need the JavaScript Class to work like this exemple if I use it in the devtools console :

```js
MySuperClass.updateSomething();
MySuperClass.somethingElse();
```

If the site doesn't have this class, it will not work...

Any idea ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.

Comment: could you explain what's the problem please ? Because I have the impression that everything is okay ?

Comment: Please provide more context in the question to make it easier to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Sorry I did modifications to have more context.